# How do I parameterize format strings used by StringContext?

Tags: scala, formatting, scala-macros

Let's say I have a line of code like this:

```
log.info(f"$name%-20s $amt%7.2f")
```

What I want is to make the `20` (the width of the `name`) something that itself can be parameterized.  How can I do that?

What if I also wanted to make the `7.2` width for `amt` also parameterized. Is that possible?

[Edit: I'm hoping to put things like `20` and `7.2` in variables so that they are not hard-coded in the format string.]

I've tried using `StringContext` directly, but it seems I don't understand whatever macro expansion is happening in:

```
StringContext(...).f(...)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it in two parts.

```
val name = "Jan"
val nLen = -10  //name length

val amt = 1.1
val ff = 5.3  //float format

s"%${nLen}s".format(name) + s"%${ff}f".format(amt)
//res0: String = Jan       1.100
```

Or in a single pass.

```
s"%${nLen}s%${ff}f".format(name, amt)
//res1: String = Jan       1.100
```

Answer (score 1):

Your were not far from the truth:

```scala
val amt= 1234.1234d
val name = "James"
println(f"|$name%20s $amt%7.2f|")
```

yields:

`|               James 1234,12|`

Regarding passing 20 and 7.2 as parameter: the template can be generated as:

```scala
val len = 20
val prec = 7.2
val template = s"$$name%${len}s $$amt%${prec}f"
```

that yields:
`$name%20 $amt%7.2f`

But string interpolation does not seem to be the solution as even desugared into StringContext, it is done at compile time, then
`s"$template`
yields `$name%20s $amt%7.2f`.

I think I had this working with another language

Comment: Thanks, but what I am hoping to find is a way to put 20 in a variable so that 20 is not hard-coded into the format string.

Comment: just edited answer: interpolation does not seem to be the solution

Answer (score 1):

you can implement yours StringContext
note:  `s"a=${a},b=${b}"` it as`StringContext("a=",",b=").s(a,b)`

```
case class Format(t: String)

// this implement is not type safe in Compile time,
implicit class MyFormat(val sc: StringContext) {

  def myFormat(args: Any*) = {
    val partIter = sc.parts.iterator
    var stringFormatArgs = List.empty[Object]
    val sb = new StringBuilder(partIter.next())

    def impl(list: List[Any]): Unit = {
      list match {
        case (_: Format) :: tail                  =>
          throw new Exception("")
        case (any: Object) :: (format: Format) :: tail =>
          sb.append(partIter.next()).append(format.t).append(partIter.next())
          stringFormatArgs = any :: stringFormatArgs
          impl(tail)
        case (any: Any) :: tail                        =>
          sb.append(any.toString).append(partIter.next())
          impl(tail)
        case Nil                                       =>
      }
    }

    impl(args.toList)
    String.format(sb.toString(), stringFormatArgs.reverse: _*)
  }
}
```

// test

```
val amt = 1234.1234d
val name = "James"
val len = Format("20s")
val prec = Format("7.2f")

myFormat"$name%$len,$amt%$prec," //"               James,1234.12,"
```